# \nameref with quotes

Tags: macros, hyperref

How can I redefine the `\nameref` command to have the referenced caption in quotes?

Here is what I have tried:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\let\oldnameref\nameref
\renewcommand{\nameref}[1]{"`\oldnameref{#1}"'} % Error: \nameref undefined.

\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}

\begin{document} 

\begin{figure}
\caption{white rectangle}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

As shown in figure~\ref{fig:figure} \nameref{fig:figure}

\end{document}
```

Expected result:

> As shown in figure 1 "white rectangle"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\nameref` is defined via `\DeclareRobustCommand` by packages `nameref` and `hyperref` in `\begin{document}`. Thus lots of things are to be considered:

- Redefinition of `\nameref` can be done in `\AtBeginDocument` *after* package `hyperref` is loaded.
- Package `letltxmacro` takes care of the internal command, defined by `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- Macro `\nameref` can be defined as robust command by `\DeclareRobustCommand`.
- The star form of `\nameref` for a reference without link should be provided also.
- Package `babel` with the appropriate language defines the shorthands `` "` `` and `"'`.

  Also package `csquotes` is worth a look.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}% some language for the shorthand
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\shorthandon{"}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \LetLtxMacro\oldnameref\nameref
  \DeclareRobustCommand*{\nameref}{%
    \@ifstar{\my@nameref*}{\my@nameref{}}%
  }%
  \newcommand*{\my@nameref}[2]{%
    "`\oldnameref#1{#2}"'%
  }%
}
\shorthandoff{"}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{white rectangle}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

As shown in figure~\ref{fig:figure} \nameref{fig:figure}

Star form: figure~\ref*{fig:figure} \nameref*{fig:figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd prefer using a different command and exploiting `csquotes`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}% some language for the shorthand

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\NewDocumentCommand{\qnameref}{sm}{%
  \enquote{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\nameref*{#2}}{\nameref{#2}}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\caption{white rectangle}
\label{fig:figure}
\end{figure}

As shown in figure~\ref{fig:figure} \qnameref{fig:figure}

Star form: figure~\ref*{fig:figure} \qnameref*{fig:figure}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}

Abbildung~\ref{fig:figure} \qnameref{fig:figure}

Abbildung~\ref*{fig:figure} \qnameref*{fig:figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you just use English, then loading `babel` is of course unnecessary. If you really want to redefine `\nameref`, then the code should become

```
\usepackage{letltxmacro} % in addition to the previous packages

\AtBeginDocument{\LetLtxMacro{\oldnameref}{\nameref}%
  \RenewDocumentCommand{\nameref}{sm}{%
    \enquote{%
      \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\oldnameref*{#2}}{\oldnameref{#2}}%
    }%
  }%
}
```